# best way, to store changed and unchanged values into MySql database

Tags: mysql, database-design

I have a MySql table that will hold a quite large amount of data (>1 million rows), with maybe 100 inserts per minute, filled and read out by two java applications.
I wonder about the best way to structure the table. There are about 10 columns representing ten measurements. If one of the measurements is not changed, I do not want to insert it again, so I don't fill my table unnecessarily.
To clarify:

```
col1  clo2  col3  col4
10    34    78    235
-1    5456  345   234
23    347   -1    -1
```

In this example, I just inserted -1 for "unchanged". Problem with this structure: if I want to get the last dataset, I have to do a lot of merging, and I'm worried about performance. So question is: is this the right approach?

I could of course just select the last value of each column on a insert and insert it again, but then each insert would entail many selects-> again, not very performant.

I also thought about a table only storing key-value pairs like this:

```
col1  col2
val1  10
val2  34
val3  78
val4 235
val2  5456
....
```

Not sure if that's a suitable approach, as I do not have the one dataset<->one complete measurement link anymore, plus the table looks kind of "messy".

Which approach would you prefer, if any, or how would you do it differently?

Comment: *"If one of the measurements is not changed, I do not want to insert it again, so I don't fill my table unnecessarily."* That doesn't make sense. Using '-1' to mean "this column didn't change" unnecessarily fills the table with invalid data.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Inserting a -1 will not save you any space or memroy.  If the column is an INT whether its null, -1, or the actual value,  you're using the same ammount of space on disk and memory.

I think you need to know how sparesely popoulated the change matrix will be with unchanged values.  If there are lots of unchanged values, the key value pair is the way to go.  IF not, you'll could eat up more space as the char(4) needed for the key column uses the equivilant space an integer, so you'll be using 2x the space for each one you change.

In your example unchanged fields are relatively rare, so the added cost of 'double space/memory' to track these as key/value would be a sum loss.

By the way, I work with tables consisting more than integers, with tens of millions of rows with overall table size in the 3-4 Gb range all the time.  While making table alterations is costly, if you stick an autoincrementing key on the table or a timestamp, it should be blazingly fast to find the current data set with  sort desc, limit 1 clause.

On novel approach would be to keep seprate table per column,then you wouldn't need a key for lookup.  That would result in the least memory/disk footprint.

In any of these for fast lookup of the 'last' value, you'll need to put some type of timestamp or autoincrementing index field.

If you never use these columns in joins or calucalation in SQL queries directly, and your #1 concern is memory / disk footpring, one final option would be to store it all values in a single varchar column as a delimited string like '123,22,333,1'.   For large numbers this uses a lot of space and wouldn't be worth it, but if you're numbers are less than 5 digits or it could out, as it's 1 byte per character (the number digits and included commas) plus one for the varchar overhead.

Comment: I see you point, but that still leaves the question: is this the propper way to do it, as to select the last dataset (which will be done quite often) I have to select each column seperately. and I cannot store the actual value, because i do not have it! and making a select on every column for every insert cannot be the answer...

Comment: @SteffenNieuwenhoven I also added a new idea--separate table per column--that would require the least memory/disk (unless you added a timestamp or index on them)

Comment: Just to clarify, are you suggesting OP store his values in a comma separated list?

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO yes, if the number of characters the integers are 4 or less digits (like his example), and his queries don't use them as integers in SQL (if for instance he's alway's pulling them out and manipulating them in code).  the most this would use would be 21 bytes per record for 4 integers.  less when the number of digits is smaller, like the numbers 1, 23, or 101.  If most fields change and aren't static, this could provide a memory/disk savings, but you need to know how sparse the changes are...

Comment: Got to love drive by downvotes without any indication of what's perceived as error.

Comment: -1 for suggesting to store multiple values in a single column. This violates 1NF.

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO it only violates 1NF if the data is being used relationally.  If the columns in the table are  only used as a value store, the concept, integer, char, etc... are meaningless and the particualar needs of the application should override aestetics

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO also, 1NF deals with not duplicating atomic data.  each string of comma separated integers are probably atomically unique.  Sure if enough we duplicate strings, you could normalize them out to another table where 1 => '1,23,221,9', 2=> '4443,221,321,1', etc..

Comment: @SteffenNieuwenhoven Thanks, I was trying to give you every possible option and concern I could think of

Comment: thank you for explaining so well! The last option was not a real option to me anyway, so I'm quite satisfied